# Show Loader while Div is Loading or Fading in or out

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout, loader

I have a webpage that is animated using a jQuery fadeIn / fadeOut with divs. Each part of the webpage is loaded by the fade In effect, and the site never navigates to a new webpage. I am looking for a loading image to display each time while the fadeIn / fadeOut is in effect. How can I program this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Tons of soloutions, [like this](http://blog.oio.de/2010/11/08/how-to-create-a-loading-animation-spinner-using-jquery/) ... You should just show before running the ajax request, and hide it on succes/error.

Comment: I disagree with the vote down and closing of this question. Where can I dispute my points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have always used [this link](http://ajaxload.info/) to generate loading images...

Then the quickest thing to do is show and hide a DIV with that loading image in, or in jQuery add and remove a class to a DIV.

In CSS that class can apply the image as a background image to the DIV and centralise it.

```
$('#yourDiv').fadeOut('slow', function() 
{
     // Code to hide or show loading image
});`
```